# Facebook client login for windows phone 7

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, authentication

I want to make a simple Facebook client for WP7 and I'm looking at how I should do the login.
There's [a tutorial here](http://buildmobile.com/facebook-in-a-windows-phone-7-app/#fbid=XBxiCmsKdBu) where the client is asked to authenticate through the browser.

I'd prefere doing the login within my application and I need more than just to 'grant acces', I need the users wall feed, friend list, messages etc.

Any idea how to do the in-app login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you cannot authenticate the user directly from your app, with out the help of browser. Facebook won't allow it.

Anyway you can take the help of the [Facebook SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/), which helps in the authentication process.

Refer this [Blog](http://igrali.com/2012/06/05/facebook-authentication-from-windows-phone-app/) for the implementation of the Facebook SDK for WP7

And additionally, you can get all the permissions that you need, by specifying the [Extended permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) in your authentication process.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the updated article from Nokia if you want to find more [here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Facebook_authentication_in_Windows_Phone_application)